# extracting a link in a html table php using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, foreach, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract a specific link from a table but is not displaying anything. It's the 3rd link in the td. I thought this would work but doesn't.

here the code:

```
<?php

$site = 'site';
$html = file_get_html($site);

foreach($html->find('td a', 3) as $element) 
echo $element->href;

?>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<tr class="evenrow team-600-359">
<td>
Aug 17
</td>

<td>
FT
</td>

<td align="right">
<a href="link1">Arsenal</a>
</td>

<td align="center">
<a href="link2">1-3</a>
</td>

<td><a href="link3">Aston Villa</a></td>


<td style="text-align:right;">60,003</td>
</td>



<td>
Premier League
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML. It can be the cause.

Check double closing of `TD` with `60,003` value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use native `DomDocument`:

```
$str = <<<STR
<tr class="evenrow team-600-359">
<td>
Aug 17
</td>

<td>
FT
</td>

<td align="right">
<a href="link1">Arsenal</a>
</td>

<td align="center">
<a href="link2">1-3</a>
</td>

<td><a href="link3">Aston Villa</a></td>


<td style="text-align:right;">60,003</td>
</td>



<td>
Premier League
</td>
</tr>
STR;



$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($str);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

echo '<pre>' . print_r($dom->saveXML($elements->item(2)), true) . '</pre>';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<td align="right">
  <a href="link1">Arsenal</a>
</td>
```